# GoPro milliseconds accuracy for creation time

Tags: video, timestamp, mp4, ffprobe, gopro

I have a GoPro Hero3 camera. When I read out the creation time (for example with ffprobe) I only get accuracy to seconds (i.e. the milliseconds are rounded). Is there a possibility to get milliseconds accuracy for the creation time of the video or is this information not stored by the GoPro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MP4s store time only up to `seconds` granularity.

Comment: Are the milliseconds just rounded down or is there an arithmetic rounding?

Comment: That depends on the writing/recording application.

Comment: Do you know how the GoPro does it?

Comment: No. But would it matter? The specs don't allow storing milliseconds. And unless you plan to hack the GoPro, you can't get that info. In either rounding scheme, your error range is 999 ms.